# Swap two elements

Tags: java, list

I wrote a simple easy code to exchange two elemnts in a list, that looks like this:

```
public void swap(Item a, Item aprev, Item b, Item bprev){
    aprev.next = b;
    bprev.next = a;
}
```

Now. If i want to actually swap two elements, nothing really changes. So if I do this:

```
SelectionSortableList list = new SelectionSortableList();
    Item item =  list.new Item("4");
    Item item1 =  list.new Item("5");
    Item item2 =  list.new Item("6");
    Item item3 =  list.new Item("7");
    list.addFront(item.value);
    list.addFront(item1.value);
    list.addFront(item2.value);
    list.addFront(item3.value);

    System.out.println(list.toString());
    list.swap(item1, item, item3, item2);
    System.out.println(list.toString());





/*    */ public abstract class SinglyLinkedList
/*    */ {
/*    */   protected SinglyLinkedList.Item head;
/*    */   
/*    */   public void addFront(String s) {
/*  6 */     if (head == null) {
/*  7 */       head = new SinglyLinkedList.Item(s);
/*    */     }
/*    */     else {
/* 10 */       SinglyLinkedList.Item insert = new SinglyLinkedList.Item(s);
/* 11 */       next = head;
/* 12 */       head = insert;
/*    */     }
/*    */   }
/*    */   
/*    */   public void add(String[] array) { String[] arrayOfString;
/* 17 */     int j = (arrayOfString = array).length; 
            for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) { String s = arrayOfString[i];
/* 18 */       addFront(s);
/*    */     }
/*    */   }
/*    */   
/*    */   public String toString()
/*    */   {
/* 24 */     if (head == null) {
/* 25 */       return "empty list";
/*    */     }
/* 27 */     String s = "";
/*    */     
/* 29 */     for (SinglyLinkedList.Item helper = head; next != null;
 helper = next) {
/* 30 */       s = String.valueOf(s) + value + ", ";
/*    */     }
/* 32 */     s = String.valueOf(s) + value;
/* 33 */     return s;
/*    */   }
/*    */   
/*    */   public abstract void sort();
/*    */   
/*    */   protected class Item
/*    */   {
/*    */     public Item next;
/*    */     public String value;
/*    */     
/*    */     public Item(String value) {
/* 44 */       this.value = value;
/*    */     }
/*    */   }
/*    */ }
```

Sorry for that mess, but it is a decompiled jar. And here is my yet unfinished class:

```
public class SelectionSortableList extends SinglyLinkedList{

public Item head;

public SelectionSortableList(){
    this.head = new Item(null);
}


public void swap(Item a, Item aprev, Item b, Item bprev){
    aprev.next = b;
    bprev.next = a;
}
```

Nothing changes and he prints me the exact same list, as before. I really have no clue, why this doesn't work.It would be great, if somebody can give me a tip, or maybe if I should write a little bit more. Thank you in beforehand :)

Comment: We really can't help without the implementation of SelectionSortableList and Item

Comment: I suggest you step through your code in your debugger to see what it is doing.

Comment: There are errors in `SinglyLinkedList`, it won't compile like that (what is `next`and `value`, I guess it's from an `Item`, but which?

Comment: And a general question: Why don't you use a list class from the Java collection framework, such as `ArrayList`?

Comment: Also, consider how your `swap()` implementation will support swapping the first element in the list. It's going to have to set `head`.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but just to keep it simple first, I wanted to test, the elements, which dont started with the head. But yes, you are right.

Comment: @AlexanderRühl Again, it's a decompiled version. He maybe doesn't show it. I don't wrote it, they gave it to me and said, it works all fine, so I trust this. But just for the syntax, so you can see, how Item is wrote. The add-methods work all fine, I have to mention

Answer (score 0):

First, it would be good to mention, why you have to or choose to go this way, instead of using a class from the Java Collections Framework.

But even if you do it for educational purposes, e.g. learn about list data structures and algorithms operating on the list, I'd recommend to first program it with the standard Java API, such as in [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/SwapelementsofJavaArrayList.htm).

Then, to understand what's going on inside, follow the source of the used classes. You'll find it at the [OpenJDK project](http://openjdk.java.net/) or for example [nicely browsable here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collections.java).

When having understood that, you can go back and implement your own version of it and (if you for example have to) use the given data structure.

---

Concerning your specific problem - I haven't tried it out (you should do that by debugging as suggested before), but I assume that when extending the class and using the same member variable name, you shadow the base class one and thus don't operate on it. So you should extend functionality, but work on the same data structure.

Comment: This is just homework for university. I'm just impressed why a complete simple code doesn't want to work and posted it here, because four eyes are better than two